# In Outlook 2010, does moving messages to the Junk E-Mail folder train Outlook for subsequent spam/junk email detection?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, spam-prevention

In Outlook 2010, When I receive a piece of spam in my Inbox and then move it into the Junk E-Mail folder (not using the Junk button, just moving it like any other folder move), does this action train Outlook's spam filter in any way?  If rather than moving the message I click the Junk button, there's an issue to "Block Sender", but nothing to classify that particular email as spam.  The fact that there is a "Block Sender" option makes me question if anything is actually happening when I drag these messages into Junk E-mail.

Update: Outlook 2011 for Mac *does* have a "Mark as Junk" option in additon to the "Block Sender" option.  This seems to be what I'm looking for in 2010.